# Export Map for each row in a shapefile

Tags: python, arcmap

I have this shapefile:

[image: Screenshot]

I would like to see *n* maps with only 1 point for each map. I try with DDT script and it returns me *n* maps but with all points in each. The question is: Is it possible to do an iterate definition query based on the Field (FID)?  this field is a numerical field so I think it would be possible to do a for loop setting first FID=0, then FID=1.etc.. but I don't know how I can do it.

Comment: You need to read the help file on [page query definitions](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/map/page-layouts/using-page-definition-queries.htm).

Comment: Unless you need it to be script/python the easy way is to use Data Driven Pages with Page Definition Queries

Comment: Is your DDT script actually an ArcPy script for DDP?  If so, please include a code snippet that illustrates what you have tried and where you are stuck.